# CakePHP component alternative in Laravel

Tags: php, cakephp, laravel

CakePHP has a structure of Components - libraries, that are used to share logic between controllers. Is there a such thing in Laravel and where to put it? I thought about Libraries, but is is not the same.

I could not found anything in the Laravel documents

Comment: Why is libraries "not the same"? Thats what libraries are for - sharing logic between controllers!

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but quoting from [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/models#libraries): _Libraries are classes that perform tasks that **aren't specific to your application**._

Comment: what are some examples of logic are you trying to share between your controllers?

Comment: For example, I am creating custom presentation logic for index() function, that will be used in some controllers. For example `ControllerA` and `ControllerN` will be using `ComponentA` logic for filtering records and columns from `ModelA` or `ModelN`.

Comment: You could make ModelX - which handles all your logic for a specific issue. See more here: http://laravel.io/topic/18/some-tips-for-laravel-newbies (and scroll to "Modeling the domain")

Comment: I will try to do like this. A little bit struggling with naming conventions, but is's ok. Please set your comment as answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, I am creating custom presentation logic for index() function, that will be used in some controllers. For example ControllerA and ControllerN will be using ComponentA logic for filtering records and columns from ModelA or ModelN

You could make ModelX, which handles all your logic for a specific issue.

[See more here](http://laravel.io/topic/18/some-tips-for-laravel-newbies) (and scroll to "Modeling the domain")

Comment: links is down, here is web archive link http://web.archive.org/web/20140115030701/http://laravel.io/topic/18/some-tips-for-laravel-newbies